# Sequencing issue when reading an ini file with Wix

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have to read an ini file with Wix. This ini file is created by the installer itself by a custom action (an exe file generates the ini file).
Problem:AppSearch (where the ini file is read) is the first step of the InstallUISequence.
Even if I call the CA before AppSearch, I get an error because when I try to read the ini file, it is not created yet..(Return="asyncWait" in the CA).
Here is the call:

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchCA" Before="AppSearch" />
</InstallUISequence>
```

Is there a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer INI searches support only files in C:\Windows folder. So using a search is not feasible.

Instead, you can try using a [custom action](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx) (custom code written by you) to read the file. I assume you want to save the result in some installer properties. So your custom action will need to receive the installation handle.

Comment: Yes, I know. My problem is that the application which generates the ini file in c:\windows runs after the Wix inifilesearch...

Comment: Writing files per-machine locations like C:\Windows right after the package is launched is not a good idea. This is why an INI search is not feasible. Instead, you can write the file in a temporary folder (for example the current user Temp folder). Your custom action can then read that file.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need is to access the data in that generated INI file, right? Do you control the way that EXE outputs the data?

If you do, you can make that data to be dumped not to INI file, but to the custom MSI table instead. Later on, your CA to read the contents of the INI file doesn't have to wait for it to gets created and you'll get rid of the AppSearch dependency.